# Doctrine: remove, then persist with Unique Values

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I have the following code. The code column of Part requires an unique value and so it throws an error when I `remove()`, then `persist()` a row with the same code value. However, the row is supposed to be removed first so there is only one value. Must I run `flush()` in between those commands?

```
        if ($existingPart) { # we found one
            if ($existingPart->getPrice() != $part->getPrice()) { # price changed
                $em->remove($existingPart); #soft-delete the old one
                $em->persist($part); # persist the new part
                $countUpdates++; # get number of updated entities
            }
        } else {
            $em->persist($part); # no existing part with same code, just add new part
            $count++; # get number of new commits    
        }                    
    }

    $em->flush();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah. I found out why: I am using softdeletable. What I needed to do is remove the unique value flag from the column definition and rather insert the following in the class annotation:

```
@UniqueEntity(fields={"deletedAt","code"})
```

This will make it check for whether the combination of `deletedAt` and `code` is unique rather than just field.